# Alter session is not altering the session properly

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle database for a project. I inserted the data in a table of the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE targetCustord(
cust_code VARCHAR2(4),
order_date DATE,
product_code VARCHAR2(8),
order_id NUMBER,
product_price NUMBER(8,2),
product_amount NUMBER(6),
transaction_id NUMBER,
PRIMARY KEY (cust_code, order_date, product_code, order_id)
USING INDEX);
```

Initially I altered the session to be

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9';
```

Which was working fine and the logs contents where in the required format. But, when I changed the session to

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF9';
```

There were no changes in the logs, neither in the table contents. The session was not altered and it was sticking to the old session.

What is the problem here ? Have I gone wrong in understanding anything ?

Can someone help me out

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remember that the oracle stores timestamps or date in its binary format, NLS parameters are just used to show the details to the client.

Now, coming to your question. 
Your table do not contain the `timestamp` column, it contains the `date` column so you need to specify the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter to see the changes in the display of the `date` data. Something like following

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

You can also check the NLS parameter value for the session, database, and instance using following views:

```
select * from NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS;
select * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS;
select * from NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS;
```

Cheers!!